# How do I replace for loops with recursion in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, grid-layout

I have 2 `for` loops that work well to create a grid with rows and columns, but I would like to improve the solution using recursion as it is more cleaner and recommended (in Functional Programming).

The desired output is a single array of pairs used in css grid

```
const createGrid = (rows,columns) => {
    let grid=[]
    for (let y = 3; y <= rows; y += 2){
        let row = []
        for (let x = 3; x <= columns; x += 2){
            let col = [y, x]
            row = [...row,col]
        }
        grid =[...grid, ...row]
    }
    return grid
}
```

Are there also any guidelines as to how to convert for loops to recursion solutions when possible?

Comment: Unless you need an arbitrary amount of dimensions, your code is totally fine.

Comment: No, it is not recommended to turn the `for` loops into recursion. What could be improved is to remove the duplication, the *nesting* of `for` loops, by using recursion.

Comment: I think you meant `grid =[...grid, row]` (or `grid.push(row)`) instead of `grid =[...grid, ...row]`

Comment: no the code works fine... i just thought it possible to replace for loops with recursion

Comment: If you don't want to create a grid (multi-dimensional array) of positions, then you shouldn't construct these `row` arrays at all but just put `grid.push(col)` (or `grid = [...grid, col]`) in the innermost loop.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that using recursion instead of a loop is "*is more cleaner and recommended*"? Do you have any other examples where loops where converted to recursion, and this improved the code?

Comment: Using recursion is not always "more cleaner and recommended" - I think you're trying to apply the wrong concept to your problem. This is totally fine.

Comment: I am learning functional programming and in books i read, recursion is recommended over for loops wherever possible... Its not a statement i concluded myself but i read from literature

Comment: It's hard to tell whether that's a valid recommendation without the full context since I don't know what books you're reading but only apply recursion when it makes sense. **No**, you **should not** be replacing every `for loop` with a recursive solution - use what's simpler, easier to read, and understand - that's the **best solution** to whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: He's talking about Functional Programming.  Should probably be using a language like Haskell (where iterative loops don't exist).  That whole "no side effects" and "stateless" bit.  IMO a bit of a "when you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail" situation going here, and "guy who doesn't know what a hammer is, listening to that guy"

Comment: @letele If it is just a learning experience: try to convert each of the loops into an individual recursive function. Or maybe refactor the inner loop into a separate function first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, on reading your code, I thought you generated one style of grid, so that `makeGrid (7, 9)` would result in something like this:

```
[
  [[3, 3], [3, 5], [3, 7], [3, 9]], 
  [[5, 3], [5, 5], [5, 7], [5, 9]], 
  [[7, 3], [7, 5], [7, 7], [7, 9]]
]
```

Instead, it returns a single array of pairs:

```
[[3, 3], [3, 5], [3, 7], [3, 9], [5, 3], [5, 5], [5, 7], [5, 9], [7, 3], [7, 5], [7, 7], [7, 9]]
```

I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one.  Bergi suggested a fix in the comments to change it to the former.  (That's what changing `grid =[...grid, ...row]` to `grid =[...grid, row]` would do.)  And the wonderful answer from Thankyou is predicated on the same assumption.

This is a problem.

When the reader can't quickly understand what your code does, it becomes much harder to maintain... even for yourself just a few weeks later.

The reason you may hear advice to replace loops with recursion is related to this.  Loops are all about explicit imperative instructions to get what you want, depending on mutating variables, which then you have to keep track of, and easily subject to off-by-one errors.  Recursion is usually more declarative, a way of saying that the result you're looking for is just a matter of combining these simpler results with our current data, and pointing out how to get the simpler results, through either a base case or a recursive call.

The advantage in readability and understandability, though, is the key, not the fact that the solution is recursive.

Don't get me wrong, recursion is one of my favorite programming techniques.  The answer from Thankyou is beatiful and elegant.  But it's not the only technique which will fix the problems that explicit `for`-loops present.  Usually one of the first things I do when trying to move junior programmer to intermediate and beyond is to replace `for`-loops with more meaningful constructs.  Most loops are trying to do one of a few things.  They're trying to convert every element of a list into something new (`map`), trying to choose some important subset of the elements (`filter`), trying to find the first important element (`find`), or trying to combine all the elements into a single value (`reduce`).  By using these instead, the code become more explicit.

Also important, as seen in the answer from Thankyou, is splitting out reusable pieces of the code so that your main function can focus on the important parts.  The version below extracts a function `rangeBy`, which adds a `step` parameter to my usual `range` function.  `range` creates a range of integers so that, for instance, `range (3, 12)` yields `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`  `rangeBy` adds an initial `step` parameter, so that `range (2) (3, 12)` yields `[3, 5, 7, 9, 11]`.

We use that `rangeBy` function along with a `map`, and its cousin, `flatMap` to make a more explicit version of your looped function:

```js
const rangeBy = (step) => (lo, hi) => 
  [... Array (Math .ceil ((hi - lo + 1) / step))] 
    .map ((_, i) => i * step  + lo)

const createGrid = (rows, columns) => 
  rangeBy (2) (3, rows) .flatMap (y => 
    rangeBy (2) (3, columns) .map (x => 
      [y, x]
    )
  )

console .log (createGrid (7, 9))
```

Knowing what `rangeBy` does, we can mentally read this as

```
const createGrid = (rows, columns) => 
  [3, 5, 7, ..., rows] .flatMap (y => 
    [3, 5, 7, ..., columns] .map (x => 
      [y, x]
    )
  )
```

Note that if you want the behavior I was expecting, you can achieve it just by replacing `flatMap` with `map` in `createGrid`.  Also, if you do so, it's trivial to add the more generic behavior that Thankyou offers, by replacing `[y, x]` with `f (x, y)` and passing `f` as a parameter.  What remains hard-coded in this version is the conversion of `rows` and `columns` into arrays of odd numbers starting with 3.  We could make the actual arrays the arguments to our function, and applying `rangeBy` outside.  But at that point, we're probably looking at a different function ideally named `cartesianProduct`.

---

So recursion is an amazing and useful tool.  But it's a tool, not a goal.  Simple, readable code, however, is an important goal.

### Update

I meant to mention this originally and simply forgot.  The following version demonstrates that the currying in `rangeBy` is far from fundamental.  We can use a single call easily:

```js
const rangeBy = (step, lo, hi) => 
  [... Array (Math .ceil ((hi - lo + 1) / step))] 
    .map ((_, i) => i * step  + lo)

const createGrid = (rows, columns) => 
  rangeBy (2, 3, rows) .flatMap (y => 
    rangeBy (2, 3, columns) .map (x => 
      [y, x]
    )
  )

console .log (createGrid (7, 9))
```

The main rationale for currying `rangeBy` is that when it's written like this:

```js
const rangeBy = (step) => (lo, hi) => 
  [... Array (Math .ceil ((hi - lo + 1) / step))] 
    .map ((_, i) => i * step  + lo)
```

we can write the more common `range` by simply applying `1` to the above.  That is,

```js
const range = rangeBy (1)

range (3, 12) //=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

This is so useful that it's become my usual style for writing functions.  But it is not a significant part of the simplification of your problem.

Comment: Ok. But please notice that the desired output is a single array of pairs. I shuffle the result of this array, and then take the first n elements of array, like a random sample.I then use this sample and use the pairs to position elements using css grid. Essentaily I am creating a dynamic venn diagram .

Comment: Right, that's what the version presented does.  You could change to the version I thought I was reading by replacing `flatMap` with `map`.

Comment: Ok. Currying is a new concept though so it will take me time to understand it. But I will tweak rangeBy and try to understand and implement it

Comment: Updated to show that the currying is useful but not essential.

Comment: Yes. I do not mind currying and understand it simplifies arguments involved. But the solution really is what I was looking for and not recursion. The hard part with functional programming is adapting to the style of writing code that declares what should happen over code the describes how the task is achieved. rangeBy declares what should happen whereas the for loops explain the control flow of how to create a grid.

Comment: @letele: Agreed. Declarative code is at the heart of functional programming.  (Alongside immutable data and the lack of side effects.)

Answer (score 3):

**primitive recursion**

Here's one possible way to make a grid using recursion -

```js
const makeGrid = (f, rows = 0, cols = 0) =>
  rows <= 0
    ? []
    : [ ...makeGrid(f, rows - 1, cols), makeRow(f, rows, cols) ]

const makeRow = (f, row = 0, cols = 0) =>
  cols <= 0
    ? []
    : [ ...makeRow(f, row, cols - 1), f(row, cols) ]

const g =
  makeGrid((x, y) => ({ xPos: x, yPos: y }), 2, 3)

console.log(JSON.stringify(g))
// [ [ {"xPos":1,"yPos":1}
//   , {"xPos":1,"yPos":2}
//   , {"xPos":1,"yPos":3}
//   ]
// , [ {"xPos":2,"yPos":1}
//   , {"xPos":2,"yPos":2}
//   , {"xPos":2,"yPos":3}
//   ]
// ]
```

The functional param `f` allows us to construct grid cells in a variety of ways

```js
const g =
  makeGrid((x, y) => [ x - 1, y - 1 ], 3, 2)

console.log(JSON.stringify(g))
// [ [ [ 0, 0 ]
//   , [ 0, 1 ]
//   ]
// , [ [ 1, 0 ]
//   , [ 1, 1 ]
//   ]
// , [ [ 2, 0 ]
//   , [ 2, 1 ]
//   ]
// ]
```

---

**work smarter, not harder**

Per Bergi's comment, you can reduce some extra argument passing by using a [*curried*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32782922/633183) cell constructor -

```js
const makeGrid = (f, rows = 0, cols = 0) =>
  rows <= 0
    ? []
    : [ ...makeGrid(f, rows - 1, cols), makeRow(f(rows), cols) ]

const makeRow = (f, cols = 0) =>
  cols <= 0
    ? []
    : [ ...makeRow(f, cols - 1), f(cols) ]

const g =
  makeGrid
    ( x => y => [ x, y ] // "curried" constructor
    , 2
    , 3
    )

console.log(JSON.stringify(g))
// [ [ [ 1, 1 ]
//   , [ 1, 2 ]
//   , [ 1, 3 ]
//   ]
// , [ [ 2, 1 ]
//   , [ 2, 2 ]
//   , [ 2, 3 ]
//   ]
// ]
```

**have your cake and eat it too**

Alternatively, we can incorporate the suggestion and still accept a binary function at the call site using partial application -

```js
const makeGrid = (f, rows = 0, cols = 0) =>
  rows <= 0
    ? []
    : [ ...makeGrid(f, rows - 1, cols)
      , makeRow(_ => f(rows, _), cols) // <-- partially apply f
      ]

const makeRow = (f, cols = 0) =>
  cols <= 0
    ? []
    : [ ...makeRow(f, cols - 1), f(cols) ]

const g =
  makeGrid
    ( (x,y) => [ x, y ] // ordinary constructor
    , 2
    , 3
    )

console.log(JSON.stringify(g))
// [ [ [ 1, 1 ]
//   , [ 1, 2 ]
//   , [ 1, 3 ]
//   ]
// , [ [ 2, 1 ]
//   , [ 2, 2 ]
//   , [ 2, 3 ]
//   ]
// ]
```

---

**Nth dimension**

Above we are limited to 2-dimensional grids. What if we wanted 3-dimensions or even more?

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const range = (start = 0, end = 0) =>
  start >= end
    ? []
    : [ start, ...range(start + 1, end) ] // <-- recursion

const map = ([ x, ...more ], f = identity) =>
  x === undefined
    ? []
    : [ f(x), ...map(more, f) ] // <-- recursion

const makeGrid = (r = [], d = 0, ...more) =>
  d === 0
    ? r
    : map(range(0, d), x => makeGrid(r(x), ...more)) // <-- recursion

const g =
  makeGrid
    ( x => y => z => [ x, y, z ] // <-- constructor
    , 2       // <-- dimension 1
    , 2       // <-- dimension 2
    , 3       // <-- dimension 3
    , // ...     <-- dimension N
    )

console.log(JSON.stringify(g))
```

Output

```js
[ [ [ [0,0,0]
    , [0,0,1]
    , [0,0,2]
    ]
  , [ [0,1,0]
    , [0,1,1]
    , [0,1,2]
    ]
  ]
, [ [ [1,0,0]
    , [1,0,1]
    , [1,0,2]
    ]
  , [ [1,1,0]
    , [1,1,1]
    , [1,1,2]
    ]
  ]
]
```

---

**any dimensions; flat result**

Per you comment, you want a *flat* array of pairs. You can achieve that by simply substituting `map` for `flatMap`, as demonstrated below -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const range = (start = 0, end = 0) =>
  start >= end
    ? []
    : [ start, ...range(start + 1, end) ]

const flatMap = ([ x, ...more ], f = identity) =>
  x === undefined
    ? []
    : [ ...f(x), ...flatMap(more, f) ] // <-- flat!

const makeGrid = (r = [], d = 0, ...more) =>
  d === 0
    ? r
    : flatMap(range(0, d), x => makeGrid(r(x), ...more))

const g =
  makeGrid
    ( x => y => [{ x, y }]  // <-- constructor
    , 2       // <-- dimension 1
    , 2       // <-- dimension 2
    , // ...     <-- dimension N
    )

console.log(JSON.stringify(g))
// [ { x: 0, y: 0 }
// , { x: 0, y: 1 }
// , { x: 1, y: 0 }
// , { x: 1, y: 1 }
// ]
```

The functional constructor demonstrates its versatility again -

```
const g =
  makeGrid
    ( x => y =>
        [[ 3 + x * 2, 3 + y * 2 ]] // whatever you want
    , 3
    , 3
    )

console.log(JSON.stringify(g))
// [[3,3],[3,5],[3,7],[5,3],[5,5],[5,7],[7,3],[7,5],[7,7]]
```

---

**learn more**

As other have show, this particular version of `makeGrid` using `flatMap` is effectively computing a [cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55711373/633183). By the time you've wrapped your head around `flatMap`, you already know the List Monad!

---

**more cake, please!**

If you're hungry for more, I want to give you a primer on one of my favourite topics in computational study: *delimited continuations*. Getting started with first class continuations involves developing an intuition on some ways in which they are used -

```js
reset
  ( call
      ( (x, y) => [[ x, y ]]
      , amb([ 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A' ])
      , amb([ '♡', '♢', '♤', '♧' ])
      )
  )

// [ [ J, ♡ ], [ J, ♢ ], [ J, ♤ ], [ J, ♧ ]
// , [ Q, ♡ ], [ Q, ♢ ], [ Q, ♤ ], [ Q, ♧ ]
// , [ K, ♡ ], [ K, ♢ ], [ K, ♤ ], [ K, ♧ ]
// , [ A, ♡ ], [ A, ♢ ], [ A, ♤ ], [ A, ♧ ]
// ]
```

Just like the List Monad, above `amb` encapsulates this notion of *ambiguous* (non-deterministic) computations. We can easily write our 2-dimensional `simpleGrid` using delimited continuations -

```js
const simpleGrid = (f, dim1 = 0, dim2 = 0) =>
  reset
    ( call
        ( f
        , amb(range(0, dim1))
        , amb(range(0, dim2))
        )
    )

simpleGrid((x, y) => [[x, y]], 3, 3)
// [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]
```

Creating an N-dimension grid is a breeze thanks to `amb` as well. The implementation has all but disappeared -

```js
const always = x =>
  _ => x

const multiGrid = (f = always([]), ...dims) =>
  reset
    ( apply
        ( f
        , dims.map(_ => amb(range(0, _)))
        )
    )

multiGrid
  ( (x, y, z) => [[ x, y, z ]] // <-- not curried this time, btw
  , 3
  , 3
  , 3
  )

// [ [0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,0,2]
// , [0,1,0], [0,1,1], [0,1,2]
// , [0,2,0], [0,2,1], [0,2,2]
// , [1,0,0], [1,0,1], [1,0,2]
// , [1,1,0], [1,1,1], [1,1,2]
// , [1,2,0], [1,2,1], [1,2,2]
// , [2,0,0], [2,0,1], [2,0,2]
// , [2,1,0], [2,1,1], [2,1,2]
// , [2,2,0], [2,2,1], [2,2,2]
// ]
```

Or we can create the desired increments and offsets using `line` in the cell constructor -

```js
const line = (m = 1, b = 0) =>
  x => m * x + b // <-- linear equation, y = mx + b

multiGrid
  ( (...all) => [ all.map(line(2, 3)) ] // <-- slope: 2, y-offset: 3
  , 3
  , 3
  , 3
  )

// [ [3,3,3], [3,3,5], [3,3,7]
// , [3,5,3], [3,5,5], [3,5,7]
// , [3,7,3], [3,7,5], [3,7,7]
// , [5,3,3], [5,3,5], [5,3,7]
// , [5,5,3], [5,5,5], [5,5,7]
// , [5,7,3], [5,7,5], [5,7,7]
// , [7,3,3], [7,3,5], [7,3,7]
// , [7,5,3], [7,5,5], [7,5,7]
// , [7,7,3], [7,7,5], [7,7,7]
// ]
```

So where do `reset`, `call`, `apply`, and `amb` come from? JavaScript does not support first class continuations, but nothing stops us from [implementing them on our own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57813405/633183) -

```js
const call = (f, ...values) =>
  ({ type: call, f, values })  //<-- ordinary object

const apply = (f, values) =>
  ({ type: call, f, values })  //<-- ordinary object

const shift = (f = identity) =>
  ({ type: shift, f })         //<-- ordinary object

const amb = (xs = []) =>
  shift(k => xs.flatMap(x => k(x))) //<-- returns ordinary object

const reset = (expr = {}) =>
  loop(() => expr)             //<-- ???

const loop = f =>
  // ...                       //<-- follow the link!
```

Given the context of your question, it should be obvious that this is a purely academic exercise. Scott's answer offers sound rationale on some of the trade-offs we make. Hopefully this section shows you that higher-powered computational features can easily tackle problems that initially appear complex.

First class continuations unlock powerful control flow for your programs. Have you ever wondered how JavaScript implements `function*` and `yield`? What if JavaScript didn't have these powers baked in? [Read the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57813405/633183) to see how we can make these (and more) using nothing but ordinary functions.

---

**continuations code demo**

See it work in your own browser! Expand the snippet below to generate grids using delimited continuations... in JavaScript! -

```js
// identity : 'a -> 'a
const identity = x =>
  x

// always : 'a -> 'b -> 'a
const always = x =>
  _ => x

// log : (string, 'a) -> unit
const log = (label, x) =>
  console.log(label, JSON.stringify(x))
  
// line : (int, int) -> int -> int
const line = (m, b) =>
  x => m * x + b
  
// range : (int, int) -> int array
const range = (start = 0, end = 0) =>
  start >= end
    ? []
    : [ start, ...range(start + 1, end) ]

// call : (* -> 'a expr, *) -> 'a expr
const call = (f, ...values) =>
  ({ type: call, f, values })

// apply : (* -> 'a expr, * array) -> 'a expr
const apply = (f, values) =>
  ({ type: call, f, values })

// shift : ('a expr -> 'b expr) -> 'b expr
const shift = (f = identity) =>
  ({ type: shift, f })

// reset : 'a expr -> 'a
const reset = (expr = {}) =>
  loop(() => expr)

// amb : ('a array) -> ('a array) expr
const amb = (xs = []) =>
  shift(k => xs .flatMap (x => k (x)))

// loop : (unit -> 'a expr) -> 'a
const loop = f =>
{ // aux1 : ('a expr, 'a -> 'b) -> 'b
  const aux1 = (expr = {}, k = identity) =>
  { switch (expr.type)
    { case call:
        return call(aux, expr.f, expr.values, k)
      case shift:
          return call
            ( aux1
            , expr.f(x => trampoline(aux1(x, k)))
            , identity
            )
      default:
        return call(k, expr)
    }
  }

  // aux : (* -> 'a, (* expr) array, 'a -> 'b) -> 'b
  const aux = (f, exprs = [], k) =>
  { switch (exprs.length)
    { case 0:
        return call(aux1, f(), k) // nullary continuation
      case 1:
        return call
          ( aux1
          , exprs[0]
          , x => call(aux1, f(x), k) // unary
          )
      case 2:
        return call
          ( aux1
          , exprs[0]
          , x =>
            call
              ( aux1
              , exprs[1]
              , y => call(aux1, f(x, y), k) // binary
              )
          )
      case 3: // ternary ...
      case 4: // quaternary ...
      default: // variadic
        return call
          ( exprs.reduce
              ( (mr, e) =>
                  k => call(mr, r => call(aux1, e, x => call(k, [ ...r, x ])))
              , k => call(k, [])
              )
          , values => call(aux1, f(...values), k)
          )
    }
  }

  return trampoline(aux1(f()))
}

// trampoline : * -> *
const trampoline = r =>
{ while (r && r.type === call)
    r = r.f(...r.values)
  return r
}

// simpleGrid : ((...int -> 'a), int, int) -> 'a array
const simpleGrid = (f, dim1 = 0, dim2 = 0) =>
  reset
    ( call
        ( f
        , amb(range(0, dim1))
        , amb(range(0, dim2))
        )
    )

// multiGrid : (...int -> 'a, ...int) -> 'a array
const multiGrid = (f = always([]), ...dims) =>
  reset
    ( apply
        ( f
        , dims.map(_ => amb(range(0, _)))
        )
    )

// : unit
log
  ( "simple grid:"
  , simpleGrid((x, y) => [[x, y]], 3, 3)
  )

// : unit
log
  ( "multiGrid:"
  , multiGrid
      ( (...all) => [ all.map(line(2, 3)) ]
      , 3
      , 3
      , 3
      )
  )
```

Comment: I'd curry `f` (and omit the `row` parameter from `makeRow`), and use `rowCount`/`columnCount` instead of `rows`/`cols`.

Comment: Note that this solves the (to me more interesting question) of creating a full `m x n` array of elements, which is what Bergi suggested was likely wanted but was rejected.  The original just creates an array of pairs.

Comment: thank you. this answer gave me more than i expected. I have an idea of recursion but now your introducing curried functions and partial applications. The concepts sound interesting.

Comment: please notice that the desired output is an array of pairs. But I think the techniques used in the answer demystified recursion a lot.

Comment: @letele thanks for the comment, I provided another update that shows you can can flatten the result. It's simply a matter of substituting `map` for `flatMap`.

Comment: This is not only a DSL but intervenes more fundamentally in the host language. You should further develop your evaluator and then give the new language a name, because that is what it is: a new language.

Answer (score 1):

Functional programming is more about higher-order functions than direct recursion. I believe the following is equivalent to your example, using `_.range` from underscore.js and `map` and `flatMap` from the standard library.

```js
const rowRange = _.range(3, rows + 1, 2);
const colRange = _.range(3, columns + 1, 2);
return rowRange.flatMap(row => colRange.map(col => [col, row]));
```