# Unrolling tree-recursion into an iterative program

Tags: node.js, recursion, iteration

I wrote a library that can generate arbitrary strings given a spec-object (https://github.com/rgrannell1/revexp) and I want to convert the function that reads the spec from a recursive algorithm to an iterative algorithm. I'm running into stackoverflow errors due to the depth of the specs I'm traversing.

I believe I need to move from using the call-stack to an explicit stack, but I've never done this before. I've read through previous posts on StackOverflow but I didn't fully understand how to apply the solutions to this problem.

Here is an example spec object.

```js
const data = {
  every: [
    {
      digit: { zero: false }
    },
    {
      repeat: {
        value: { digit: {} }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and a minimal example of how the algorithm currently traverses the spec and generates a string matching the spec.

```js
const fromSpec = (data) => {
  if (data.every) {
    return fromSpec.every(data)
  } else if (data.digit) {
    return fromSpec.digit()
  } else if (data.repeat) {
    return fromSpec.repeat(data.repeat)
  }
}

fromSpec.digit = () => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
}

fromSpec.every = part => {
  let message = ''

  for (const elem of part.every) {
    message += fromSpec(elem)
  }

  return message
}



fromSpec.repeat = part => {
  let message = ''
  
  // -- just using fixed repeat for the example
  for (let ith = 0; ith < 10; ++ith) {
    message += fromSpec(part.value)
  }

  return message
}

const result = fromSpec(data)
result // 1034856872
```

I'd appreciate any advice on how to traverse this data-structure and generate an output string in an iterative rather than recursive fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example modifies the code to use a stack data structure. Data on the stack is processed incrementally, with new data possibly added on each iteration.

```js
const fromSpec = (data) => {
    const stack = [data];
    let message = '';
    while (stack.length > 0) {
        const item = stack.pop();
        // Assumption based on the code in the question:
        //   'every', 'digit', and 'repeat' keys are mutually exclusive.
        if (item.every) {
            // Add items in reverse order, so that items are popped off the stack
            // in the original order.
            for (let i = item.every.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                stack.push(item.every[i]);
            }
        } else if (item.digit) {
            message += String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
        } else if (item.repeat) {
            for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                stack.push(item.repeat.value);
            }
        }
    }
    return message;
}
```

An alternative approach would be required for a more complicated scenario (e.g., when a node in the tree requires processing both 1) when it's initially encountered in the traversal and 2) after all its children have been traversed).

The following links may be relevant.

- https://web.archive.org/web/20120227170843/http://cs.saddleback.edu/rwatkins/CS2B/Lab%20Exercises/Stacks%20and%20Recursion%20Lab.pdf
- [https://web.archive.org/web/20161206082402/https://secweb.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs361/web/website/Lectures/recursionConversion/page/recursionConversion.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20161206082402/https://secweb.cs.odu.edu/%7Ezeil/cs361/web/website/Lectures/recursionConversion/page/recursionConversion.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's natural to write `RevExp.toString` as a recursive program because it is expected to process a recursively structured input. However because recursive programs can lead to deep stacks, it's not uncommon to flatten a recursive process to an iterative one.

Good programmers know that maintaining complexity goes a long way in sustaining our sanity. I want to keep my recursive program and I want the computer to handle flattening the process for me. Can I have my cake and eat it too?

Here's another way to look a the problem -

```js
// example1.js

import { concat, upper, digit, str, toString } from './RevExp.js'

const licensePlate =
  concat(upper(), upper(), upper(), str("-"), digit(), digit(), digit())

console.log(toString(licensePlate))
console.log(toString(licensePlate))
console.log(toString(licensePlate))
// RFX-559
// VKT-794
// KSF-823
```

Let's begin writing the `RevExp` module. We'll start by creating constructors for each of our expression types -

```js
// RevExp.js

const str = (value = "") =>
  ({ type: str, value })

const lower = () =>
  ({ type: lower })

const upper = () =>
  ({ type: upper })

const digit = ({ zero = true } = {}) =>
  ({ type: digit, zero })

const concat = (...exprs) =>
  ({ type: concat, exprs })
```

Now let's work on `RevExp.toString` -

```js
// RevExp.js (continued)

import { inRange } from './Rand.js'

const toString = (e) =>
{ switch (e.type)
  { case str:
      return String(e.value)
    case lower:
      return String.fromCharCode(inRange(97, 122))
    case upper:
      return String.fromCharCode(inRange(65, 90))
    case digit:
      return e.zero
      ? String(inRange(0, 9))
      : String(inRange(1, 9))
    case concat:
      return e.exprs.reduce((r, v) => r + toString(v), "")
    default: throw Error(`unsupported expression type: ${e.type}`)
  }
}

export { lower, upper, digit, alpha, repeat, concat, str, toString }
```

It should be possible to make complex expressions by combining several simple expressions. And we imagine some new types like `alpha`, and `repeat` -

```js
// example2.js

import { alpha, digit, repeat, concat, str, toString } from './RevExp.js'

const segment =
  concat(alpha(), digit(), alpha(), digit(), alpha())

const serial =
  concat
    ( repeat
        ( concat(segment, str("-"))
        , { count: 4 }
        )
    , segment
    )

console.log(toString(serial))
console.log(toString(serial))
console.log(toString(serial))
// F3Q7U-b6k8Q-R8e3A-a2q3M-j0a9k
// g6G3w-h2O3O-b8O3k-L4p1y-m5I0y
// m6E0M-A4C2y-K3g0M-d7X7j-w8v5G
```

And add corresponding support in the `RevExp` module -

```js
// RevExp.js (enhanced)

import { inRange, sample } from './Rand.js'

const str = // ...
const lower = // ...
const upper = // ...
const digit = // ...
const concat = // ...

const alpha = () =>
  oneOf(upper(), lower())

const oneOf = (...exprs) =>
  ({ type: oneOf, exprs })

const repeat = (expr = {}, { count = 10 } = {}) =>
  ({ type: repeat, expr, count })

const toString = (e) =>
{ switch (e.type)
  { case str: // ...
    case lower: // ...
    case upper: // ...
    case digit: // ...
    case concat: // ...
    case oneOf:
      return toString(sample(e.exprs))
    case repeat:
      return toString(concat(...Array(e.count).fill(e.expr)))
    default: // ...
  }
}

export { /* ..., */ alpha, oneOf, repeat }
```

---

Now let's transform the recursive program to an iterative one. And without having to think about the stack or mutate state as the program runs, too!

```js
// RevExp.js (stack-safe)

// ...
import * as Str from './Str.js'
import { loop, recur, call } from './TailRec.js'

// ...
const toString = (e = {}) =>
  loop(toStringTailRec, e)

const toStringTailRec = e =>
{ switch (e.type)
  { case str: // ...
    case lower: // ...
    case upper: // ...
    case digit: // ...
    case concat:
      return e.exprs.length
        ? call
            ( Str.concat
            , recur(e.exprs[0])
            , recur(concat(...e.exprs.slice(1)))
            )
        : Str.empty
    case oneOf:
      return recur(sample(e.exprs))
    case repeat:
      return recur(concat(...Array(e.count).fill(e.expr)))
    default: throw Error(`unsupported expression type: ${e.type}`)
  }
}

export { /*...*/, toString } // <-- don't export toStringTailRec helper
```

And here are the remaining modules, `Str`, `Rand`, and `TailRec` -

```js
// Str.js

const empty =
  ""

const concat = (a = "", b = "") =>
  a + b

export { empty, concat }
```

```js
// Rand.js

const rand = (n = 2) =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * n)

const inRange = (min = 0, max = 1) =>
  rand(max - min + 1) + min

const sample = (t = []) =>
  t[rand(t.length)]

export { rand, inRange, sample }
```

Writing modules is an important factor in creating reusable code. This `TailRec` module was written in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57743504/633183) and can be reused, *without modification<sup>1</sup>*, to meet our program's needs.

Now we can rely on recursively structured programs without having to introduce complexity or requiring a change in how we think every time we encounter a recursive problem. Write the module once, reuse as needed -

```js
// TailRec.js

const identity = x =>
  x

const call = (f, ...values) =>
  ({ type: call, f, values })

const recur = (...values) =>
  ({ type: recur, values })

const loop = (f, ...init) =>
{ const aux1 = (e, k) =>
    e.type === recur
      ? call(aux, e.values, r => call(aux1, f(...r), k))
  : e.type === call
      ? call(aux, e.values, r => call(aux1, e.f(...r), k))
  : call(k, e)

  const aux = (exprs, k) =>
    call
      ( exprs.reduce
          ( (mr, e) =>
              k => call(mr, r => call(aux1, e, x => call(k, [ ...r, x ])))
          , k => call(k, [])
          )
      , k
      )

  return run(aux1(f(...init), identity))
}

const run = r =>
{ while (r && r.type === call)
    r = r.f(...r.values)
  return r
}

export { loop, call, recur }
```

In the end, the approach here is virtually the same as yours. However instead of representing expressions writing JS objects by hand, we use functions, which can be parameterized and composed, and can handle the tedious and precarious assembly for us. Programmer sanity maintained -

```js
// example2.js

// ...
console.log(serial)
```

```js
{ type: concat
, exprs:
    [ { type: repeat
      , expr:
          { type: concat
          , exprs:
              [ { type: concat
                , exprs:
                    [ { type: oneOf, exprs: [ { type: lower }, { type: upper } ] }
                    , { type: digit, zero: true }
                    , { type: oneOf, exprs: [ { type: lower }, { type: upper } ] }
                    , { type: digit, zero: true }
                    , { type: oneOf, exprs: [ { type: lower }, { type: upper } ] }
                    ]
                }
              , { type: str, value: "-" }
              ]
          }
      , count: 4
      }
    , { type: concat
      , exprs:
        [ { type: concat
          , exprs:
              [ { type: oneOf, exprs: [ { type: lower }, { type: upper } ] }
              , { type: digit, zero: true }
              , { type: oneOf, exprs: [ { type: lower }, { type: upper } ] }
              , { type: digit, zero: true }
              , { type: oneOf, exprs: [ { type: lower }, { type: upper } ] }
              ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

I hope this was seen as an exciting way to see the same problem from a different perspective. If you end up using the `TailRec` module, see the original post for additional explanation. I'm happy to answer any follow-up questions.

---

<sup>1.</sup> Minor formatting changes and variable renaming for consistency with this answer

Comment: That is an interesting approach; I initially started with a builder-pattern style builder not too disimilar to this approach (perhaps a little less FP) but decided to move to more declarative recursive-JSON (https://github.com/rgrannell1/revexp/blob/master/src/specs/json-config.ts) for SEXPR benefits of making validation, metaprogramming, and interlanguage IOP easier. 

The approach you included is perfectly useable through, and is easier to compose new changes on top of

Comment: Thanks for reading and commenting. The approach here can be seen as one level of abstraction apart from the handwritten object literals. The FP expressions build the recursive JS objects for us, and `toString` operates like your `fromSpec`. I made an update to show what it looks like when you `console.log` an expression.

Comment: After writing this yesterday, I thought it would be interesting to support `RevExp.toString(RevExp.fromRegExp(/[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{3}/))` to output (eg) `RFX-559`. This would mean writing a basic RegExp lexer/parser for the feature set you wish to support. It could be even better than either approach presented here 

Comment: fromRegExp was something I was planning on adding! I worked on the JSON-based component first because I didn't want to expression JSONs entire AST via regular expressions 