# Stack safety of trampoline when the interpreter loop itself is recursive

Tags: python, recursion, functional-programming, stack-overflow, trampolines

I'm implementing a Trampoline in Python, in order to write recursive functions with stack safety (since CPython does not feature TCO). It looks like this:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

A = TypeVar('A', covariant=True)


class Trampoline(Generic[A], ABC):
    """
    Base class for Trampolines. Useful for writing stack safe-safe
    recursive functions.
    """
    @abstractmethod
    def _resume(self) -> 'Trampoline[A]':
        """
        Let this trampoline resume the interpreter loop
        """
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def _handle_cont(
        self, cont: Callable[[A], 'Trampoline[B]']
    ) -> 'Trampoline[B]':
        """
        Handle continuation function passed to `and_then`
        """
        pass

    @property
    def _is_done(self) -> bool:
        return isinstance(self, Done)

    def and_then(self, f: Callable[[A], 'Trampoline[B]']) -> 'Trampoline[B]':
        """
        Apply ``f`` to the value wrapped by this trampoline.

        Args:
            f: function to apply the value in this trampoline
        Return:
            Result of applying ``f`` to the value wrapped by \
            this trampoline
        """
        return AndThen(self, f)

    def map(self, f: Callable[[A], B]) -> 'Trampoline[B]':
        """
        Map ``f`` over the value wrapped by this trampoline.

        Args:
            f: function to wrap over this trampoline
        Return:
            new trampoline wrapping the result of ``f``
        """
        return self.and_then(lambda a: Done(f(a)))

    def run(self) -> A:
        """
        Interpret a structure of trampolines to produce a result

        Return:
            result of intepreting this structure of \
            trampolines
        """
        trampoline = self
        while not trampoline._is_done:
            trampoline = trampoline._resume()

        return cast(Done[A], trampoline).a


class Done(Trampoline[A]):
    """
    Represents the result of a recursive computation.
    """
    a: A

    def _resume(self) -> Trampoline[A]:
        return self

    def _handle_cont(self,
                     cont: Callable[[A], Trampoline[B]]) -> Trampoline[B]:
        return cont(self.a)


class Call(Trampoline[A]):
    """
    Represents a recursive call.
    """
    thunk: Callable[[], Trampoline[A]]

    def _handle_cont(self,
                     cont: Callable[[A], Trampoline[B]]) -> Trampoline[B]:
        return self.thunk().and_then(cont)  # type: ignore

    def _resume(self) -> Trampoline[A]:
        return self.thunk()  # type: ignore


class AndThen(Generic[A, B], Trampoline[B]):
    """
    Represents monadic bind for trampolines as a class to avoid
    deep recursive calls to ``Trampoline.run`` during interpretation.
    """
    sub: Trampoline[A]
    cont: Callable[[A], Trampoline[B]]

    def _handle_cont(self,
                     cont: Callable[[B], Trampoline[C]]) -> Trampoline[C]:
        return self.sub.and_then(self.cont).and_then(cont)  # type: ignore

    def _resume(self) -> Trampoline[B]:
        return self.sub._handle_cont(self.cont)  # type: ignore

    def and_then(  # type: ignore
        self, f: Callable[[A], Trampoline[B]]
    ) -> Trampoline[B]:
        return AndThen(
            self.sub,
            lambda x: Call(lambda: self.cont(x).and_then(f))  # type: ignore
        )
```

Now, I need a monadic sequence operator. My initial take looked like this:

```py
from typing import Iterable

from functools import reduce


def sequence(iterable: Iterable[Trampoline[A]]) -> Trampoline[Iterable[A]]:
    def combine(result: Trampoline[Iterable[A]], ta: Trampoline[A]) -> Trampoline[Iterable[A]]:
        return result.and_then(lambda as_: ta.map(lambda a: as_ + (a,)))

    return reduce(combine, iterable, Done(()))
```

That works, but the overhead of all the function calls resulting from reducing a long list of trampolines in this way absolutely kills performance.

So instead I tried this:

```py
def sequence(iterable: Iterable[Trampoline[A]]) -> Trampoline[Iterable[A]]:
    def thunk() -> Trampoline[Iterable[A]]:
        return Done(tuple([t.run() for t in iterable]))
    
    return Call(thunk)
```

Now, my gut feeling is that the second solution of `sequence` isn't stack safe because it call's `run`, which means that `run` will be calling `run` during interpretation (through `Call.thunk` but non the less). However, I can't seem to produce a stack overflow no matter how I mix and match.

For example, I thought this should do it:

```py
t, *ts = [sequence(Done(v) for v in range(2)) for _ in range(10000)]

def combine(t1, t2):
    return t1.and_then(lambda _: t2)

final = reduce(combine, ts, t)
final.run()  # My gut feeling says this should overflow the stack, but it doesn't
```

I've tried countless other examples, but no stack overflow. My gut feeling remains that this shouldn't work.

I need someone to convince me that trampolining the interpreter loop in this way is actually stack safe, or show me an example where it overflows the stack

Comment: Are you interested in another implementation? - [https://pypi.org/project/trampoline/](https://pypi.org/project/trampoline/)

Comment: I like the api definitely, nice with the simplicity of using generators!

For my use case I need to be able to chain together trampolined functions (ie monadic bind called `and_then` in my example) and trampoline combinators (e.g `sequence` as described`. I'm not sure how that would work with your solution? Probably its possible.

Also, how does it work if you want to trampoline a generator function? (ie where the yielded values doesn't indicate a recursive call but the actual return values of the function?

Comment: It is not my solution, just wanted to point it out in case you had not seen it.

Comment: It makes good sense to put the interpreter on a trampoline. Using continuation passing style is an effective way to convert a recursive process to a linear one. I use this same technique in another (JS) [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57743504/633183).

Answer (score 0):

The recursion you need to cause a stack overflow during interpretation:

```py
sequence([sequence([sequence([sequence([...
```

Comment: I don't know python but if you are recursive within a monad, i.e. within bind/chain/then then you need a trampoline- or continuation-monad, where the former would be simpler than the latter. Normal trampolines depend on tail recursion. If you want to relax this restriction you can also implement a trampoline modulon cons, which allows you to place the recursive step within a constructor apllication. I wrote a lot about trampolines. You can find it on my profile.