# How can I extract a nested array of objects and put them in the core array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am working on a functionality where I need to group some items and also ungroup them.

Some days ago I asked this question:
[How can I group specific items within an object in the same array and delete them from the core array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66298505/how-can-i-group-specific-items-within-an-object-in-the-same-array-and-delete-the?noredirect=1#comment117247127_66298505) where a couple of people helped me solving the grouping part. But it is very related to this question.

What I need to do now, is to ungroup the items with the exact same requirement: ungroup the `checked === true` group and put the items back from where they came from and remove all duplicates.

Here is a reproducible demo with both functionalities: https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-react-grouping-forked-rmwhr?file=/src/App.tsx

And here the relevante piece of code:

```js
const handleUngroupingQuestions = (): void => {
    const questionAddedCopy: VariableConfig[] = [...questionAdded]
    const filteredByChecked: VariableConfig[] = questionAddedCopy.filter((q: VariableConfig) => isCheck.includes(q.id))

    if (isCheck.length) {
      setCheck([])

      const extractGroup = (i: number): VariableConfig[] => filteredByChecked[i].questionGroup
      const addChecked = (q: VariableConfig): VariableConfig => ({ ...q, questionGroup: [] })

      // @TODO
      // Remove this when we have a proper data structure
      clearVariable()

      const nestChecked = (qs: VariableConfig[], found = false) =>
        qs.flatMap((q: VariableConfig, i: number) => {
          if (filteredByChecked.includes(q)) {
            if (found) {
              return []
            } else {
              found = true
              return [...[addChecked(q)], ...extractGroup(i)]
            }
          } else {
            return [q]
          }
        })

      const getNew = [...nestChecked(questionAdded)]

      console.log({ getNew: JSON.stringify(getNew, null, 2) })

      addQuestion(getNew.filter((g, i, a) => a.indexOf(g) === i))
    }
  }
```

For some reason right now I am getting an error:

```
Cannot read property 'questionGroup' of undefined
```

Something is happening with an index.

So what I need is to group all of the items with the checked property being true. Then click on `ungroup` and bring the items back to its original position and deleting the current group. I must be able to do that even when there are multiple groups of questions.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with an array length 5, then group to create an array length 3 (with the nested array inside the 2nd element of this)

Then in your handleUngroupingQuestions function, the first variable filteredByChecked is defined via the filter function as an array with 1 element only (the single element with the nested array questionGroup)

```
const filteredByChecked: VariableConfig[] = questionAdded.filter(
      (q: VariableConfig) => q.checked === true
    );
```

Then when you try to ungroup, you are passing the length 3 array to the function, which takes a different index (the second element, index 1):

```
const extractGroup = (i: number) => {
      console.log(i);
      return filteredByChecked.length ? filteredByChecked[i].questionGroup : [];
    };
```

The i being passed to extractGroup here is 1, which does not exist as filteredByChecked is a length 1 array.

Please consider this single map function as your ungrouping handler:

```
const handleUngroupingQuestions = (): void => {
    const extractGroups = (groupedArr: Array) => {
      return groupedArr.flatMap((x) =>
        x.questionGroup.length > 0 ? [...x.questionGroup] : x
      );
    };

    const newQs = extractGroups(questionAdded);
    const sortedQs = newQs.sort((a, b) =>
      parseInt(a.name.slice(-1), 10) > parseInt(b.name.slice(-1), 10) ? 1 : -1
    );

    console.log(sortedQs);
    addQuestion(sortedQs);
  };
```

[image: Edit TS-React Grouping (forked)]