# How can I change and keep the value of a variable inside a recursive function without passing it as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
function newtonRaphson(x, count){
  while(count > 0){
    var previousValue = 0
    if(previousValue === 0){
      previousValue = x/2
    } 
    var y = (previousValue + (x/previousValue))/2 
    previousValue = y
    console.log(previousValue, count)
    return newtonRaphson(x, count - 1)
  }  
  return y
}
```

I have this function that is supposed to perform the Newton Raphson method, it would look like this:

- x = 20
- count = 4
- previousValue(0) = 10
- y(1) = (10 + (20/10))/2 = 6
- previousValue = 6
- y(2) = (6 + (20/6))/2 = 4.666
- previousValue = 4.666
- y(3) = (4.666 + (20/4.666))/2 = 4.476
- previousValue = 4.476
- y(4) = (4.476+ (20/4.476))/2 = 4.472

My question is, is there a way I can maintain previousValue between iterations without passing it to the function? Because x needs to be passed no matter what, as well as count, but I also need to tell the function what the previousValue is, so I'm at a loss

Comment: Use a global variable?

Comment: Is there any way to do it without a global variable?

Comment: Maybe you could wrap it in another function and make it local to the wrapper function?

Comment: I have tried and failed, the global variable is a good solution, don't know if it's possible without it though.

Comment: What did you try that failed? How did it fail?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific, I tried to use a wrapper function, but just like before the value of previousValue keeps resetting every iteration

Comment: Passing it as an argument is the right thing to do in a recursive function. Not sure why you're trying to avoid that.

Comment: Please show your work on your wrapper function. We can't tell what's going on without seeing it. But @Bergi is right; passing it is the way to go. What's preventing that from working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is confused.

First off, while it's called `newtonRaphson`, it seems to be only for a very specific case of [the Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), that of finding square roots using the [Babylonian Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method).  So ideally it should have a better name.

It tries to simultaneously solve the problem recursively and with a `while`-loop.  We need to choose one or the other.  Here we choose a recursive version.

Then we note that these lines make no real sense:

```js
    var previousValue = 0
    if(previousValue === 0){
      previousValue = x/2
    }
```

This is a ridiculously round-about way of writing

```js
    var previousValue = x/2
```

You ask about doing this without passing the previous value to the recursive function.  You could, just by tracking it at a higher scope.  (Please, please, not the global scope!)  It might look like this:

```js
const sqrt = (x, count) => {
  let prev = x / 2
  const _sqrt = (count) => {
    if (count <= 0) return prev
    prev = (prev + (x / prev)) / 2
    return _sqrt (count - 1)
  }
  return _sqrt (count)
}

console .log (sqrt (25, 1)) //=> 7.25
console .log (sqrt (25, 2)) //=> 5.349137931034482
console .log (sqrt (25, 3)) //=> 5.011394106532552
console .log (sqrt (25, 4)) //=> 5.000012953048684
console .log (sqrt (25, 5)) //=> 5.000000000016778
console .log (sqrt (25, 6)) //=> 5
```

But I would not recommend this at all.  Recursion is simplest when you pass the necessary variables into the function.  And this is not hard to do, either with a defaulted parameter, like this:

```js
const sqrt = (x, count, prev = x / 2) =>
  count <= 0
    ? prev
    : sqrt (x, count - 1, (prev + (x / prev)) / 2)
```

or with a public wrapper around an internal recursive helper function, like this:

```js
const _sqrt = (x, count, prev) =>
  count <= 0
    ? prev
    : _sqrt (x, count - 1, (prev + (x / prev)) / 2)

const sqrt = (x, count) => 
  _sqrt (x, count, x / 2)
```

Of the two, I usually prefer the defaulted parameter, but there are some [potential problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63708667/1243641) with them, especially if you are not in control of how your function is called.  Then the public/internal split makes sense.