# Recursively create a parent and child string for every child and it's child

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm attempting to create an array of objects as the final output which includes the parent name and it's children. The `id` would be the last child in the name

Sample output I'm trying to achieve :

```
[
{id:1,name:"1"},
{id:2,name:"1-2"},
{id:3,name:"1-2-3"},
{id:4,name:"1-2-4"}
]
```

Code:

```js
let item = {
  id: 1,
  name: "1",
  children: [{
    id: 2,
    name: "2",
    children: [{
        id: 3,
        name: "3",
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "4",
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }]
}


const createList = (item) => {

  let name = item.children.map(e => {
    return createList(e)
  })
  return item.name + "-" + name
}

console.log(createList(item))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple recursion will do the trick:

```js
let item = {
  id: 1,
  name: "1",
  children: [{
    id: 2,
    name: "2",
    children: [{
        id: 3,
        name: "3",
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "4",
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }]
}

var result = []


const createList = (items, acc) => {
  items.forEach(item => {
    const newAcc = {
      id: item.id,
      name: acc ? `${acc.name}-${item.name}` : `${item.name}`
    }
    result.push(newAcc)
    createList(item.children, newAcc)
  })
}

createList([item], null)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with recursion, but the map function is probably not the best choice for this. Map function doesn't work the way you might expect when there is only one element in the array, as it is not meant to be used to process lists in such a way, but only to "map" data.

Try switching to a for loop or foreach and building the string yourself.

Example:

```js
let sample = {
  id: 1,
  name: "1",
  children: [{
    id: 2,
    name: "2",
    children: [{
        id: 3,
        name: "3",
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "4",
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }]
};

function buildArray(input, parentName) {
  let output = [];

  for (let item of input) {
    let name = parentName ? `${parentName}-${item.name}` : item.name;
    output.push({ id: item.id, name: name });
    if (item.children) {
      output = output.concat(buildArray(item.children, name));
    }
  }

  return output;
}

let result = buildArray(sample.children, sample.name);

let output = document.getElementById('myresult');
output.innerText = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<p id="myresult"></p>
```

Comment: I would have marked this as accepted but it was missing the initial parent. But nevertheless a good solution too. Thank you very much for your time and I appreciate the advice in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can do this more simply.  I'd prefer code like this:

```js
const convert = ({id, name, children}, prefix = '') => [
  {id, name: prefix + name},
  ...children .flatMap (c => convert (c, prefix + name + '-'))
]

const sample = {id: 1, name: "1", children: [{id: 2, name: "2", children: [{id: 3, name: "3", children: []}, {id: 4, name: "4", children: []}]}]}
  
console .log (convert (sample))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note that our recursion bottoms without an explicit case for it because mapping over an empty array returns an empty array, without making further calls.  And that result is just folded into our accumulation by `flatMap`.

If you prefer not to include default parameters (and there are some [good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63708667) for that preference), you could simply wrap an internal version of this function into a public function, supplying the initial `prefix` value to that internal one.  This would also allow us to simplify the function reference passed to `flatMap`:

```js
const _convert = (prefix = '') => ({id, name, children}) => [
  {id, name: prefix + name},
  ...children .flatMap (_convert (prefix + name + '-'))
]

const convert = _convert ('')

const sample = {id: 1, name: "1", children: [{id: 2, name: "2", children: [{id: 3, name: "3", children: []}, {id: 4, name: "4", children: []}]}]}
  
console .log (convert (sample))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```