# Need generating a list from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm working in a front-end in which I receive an order from the database and I need to generate a PDF but only wit 10 items per page. I need to generate a list of orders with the same attributes but with 10 items each until the original order items list finishes.

Here an example:

```
const order = {
    name: 'services',
    items: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
}

const paginate = (order, pages, start, end) => {

    if (order.items.length <= end) {
        return pages.concat({
            name: order.name,
            items: order.items.slice(start, end)
        })
    } else {
        start += 4
        end += 4
        paginate(order, start, end)
    }

}
```

but that gives me the Maximum call stack size exceeded error. For this example I'm trying to split the order with 3 items. Any help will be really good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to address some problems in your code like:

1. You've to update the `pages` parameter in your recursive call which you're not doing.
2. Also, I'm not sure why you have a hard-coded value of `4` for the increment of `start` and `end`, although you mentioned you want to split the order with 3 items.

##### My approach:

1. As a base(terminating) case, check if the `start <= length of items`.
   1.1. If yes, return the `pages` array.
2. Calculate the end for the current call.
3. Update the `pages` array.
4. Make the recursive call with the updated `end` and `pages` array.

```js
const order = {
  name: 'services',
  items: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
}
// Time complexity: O(n), n being #of items in the order.items array.
const paginate = (order, itemsPerPage, start = 0, pages = []) => {
  // base case
  if (start >= order.items.length) {
    return pages; // Space Complexity O(n) for pages + depth of call stack used ~ O(n)
  }
  const end = start + itemsPerPage;
  pages.push({
    name: order.name,
    items: order.items.slice(start, end)
  });
  return paginate(order, itemsPerPage, end, pages);
}
const paginatedOrders = paginate(order, 3); // <-- update to 4 if you need that
console.log(paginatedOrders);
```

**SIDENOTE:**

As you can see it is tail recursive code(and although compilers optimize them behind the scenes), writing iterative approach for it is easier. The asymptotic time and space complexity remains ***`O(n)`*** although you can save the stack space when you use the iterative approach which in recursive code approximates to *`(n / itemsPerPage)`*.

Answer (score 2):

I would separate the code to chunk an array into size `n`-pieces into a reusable utility function, and use that to build your `paginate` function.

Here is one way to do this, with a recursive `chunk` function

```js
const chunk = (n) => (xs) =>
  xs.length <= n ? [[...xs]] : [xs.slice(0, n), ... chunk(n)(xs.slice(n))]

const paginate = ({name, items}, n) => 
  chunk(n)(items).map(xs => ({name, items: xs})) 

const order = {name: 'services', items: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']}

console.log(paginate(order, 3))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

`paginate` is simple: we chunk the array into `n`-sized pieces, and then map those pieces into objects which carry your `name` property through, and use the current array as `items`.

`chunk` is the important part here, and it's a reusable function which might easily be included in a utility library.  If our input is shorter than the chunk length, we return an array which includes only (a copy of) our input.  Otherwise we return an array which starts with and array of the first `n` items and is followed by the result of a recursive call on the rest of the array.

This version is subject to recursion depth limits.  If the number of pages exceeds that limit, you will be better off using a non-recursive version<sup>1</sup> which tracks the indices instead.  While we can make this tail recursive easily enough, since most engines are still not (as of this writing, 9 years after specification!) [performing tail-call optimization](https://compat-table.github.io/compat-table/es6/?proper%20tail%20calls#test-proper_tail_calls_(tail_call_optimisation)), it doesn't add much current benefit.

But for completeness's sake, we can rewrite in tail-call fashion like this:

```js
const chunk = (n) => (xs, r = []) =>
  xs.length == 0 ? r : chunk(n)(xs.slice(n), r.concat([xs.slice(0, n)]))
```

or like this:

```js
const chunk = (n) => (xs) => _chunk(n)(xs, [])

const _chunk = (n) => (xs, r) =>
  xs.length == 0 ? r : _chunk(n)(xs.slice(n), r.concat([xs.slice(0, n)]))
```

The first one is to my eyes cleaner, but if it's a publicly available function, it might run into [some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63708667), which are fixed by the second one.

---

<sup>1</sup> Perhaps something like

```js
const chunk = (n) => (xs) => 
  Array.from({length: Math.ceil(xs.length / n)}, (_, i) => xs.slice(i * n, (i + 1) * n))
```

Comment: `chunk` reusable utility is wonderful. Also, thanks for adding on the tail-call optimization link as well.

Answer (score 1):

it's like this?

```js
const order = {
    name: 'services',
    items: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
}

function paginate(order, pageSize = 4){
  return new Array(Math.ceil(order.items.length/pageSize)).fill('').map((_, index) => {
    return {
      name: order.name,
      items: order.items.slice(pageSize*index, pageSize*(index+1))
    }
  })
}

console.log(paginate(order,4))
```