# about JS functioning

Tags: javascript, recursion, memory

Here is an example of a string reverse function with recursion.

I'd like to understand why:

(1) If I switch the return line inner actions like this:

```
return word.charAt(0) + reversed(word.substring(1))
```

I get the string again but not reversed.

(2) Where the 'word.charAt()' letters are being saved through the nested calls (and overall if it's the same with a regular function), memory wise what I miss here, what keeps them accumulated with tact and where are they 'going'.

I'd like an explanation of some kind to how the memory concept works in js to understand better the relations as I code ( I think especially in and out of functions in my case).

```
var reverseArray = reversedItems(arr)

function reverseAll(items) {
  return items.map(function reversed(word) {
    if (word === "") return ""
    return reversed(word.substring(1)) + word.charAt(0)
  })
}
```

Comment: Rather than "memory", I think the concept you need to read up on is "variable scope". Perhaps this will help you: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500431/157957).

Comment: I'd recommend "playing computer" with a pencil and paper and trace out every single step, using a short string. Using a debugger is also an option, but that can end up being even more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You should understand the `reversed` function separately before concerning yourself with `reverseAll` -

```js
function reverse(word) {
  if (word === "") return ""
  return reverse(word.substring(1)) + word.charAt(0)
}

console.log(reverse("hello world"))
```

Starting with `reverse("hello_world")` we can easily trace the evaluation. Whenever the input `word` is non-empty, a new stack frame is opened with the recursive call to the sub-problem `reverse(word.substring(1))`. The `... + word.charAt(0)` portion remains in the calling frame and only resumes after the descendant frame returns -

```js
reverse("hello world") =
reverse("ello world") + "h" =
reverse("llo world") + "e" + "h" =
reverse("lo world") + "l" + "e" + "h" =
reverse("o world") + "l" + "l" + "e" + "h" =
reverse(" world") + "o" + "l" + "l" + "e" + "h" =
reverse("world") + " " + "o" + "l" + "l" + "e" + "h" =
reverse("orld") + "w" + " " + "o" + "l" + "l" + "e" + "h" =
reverse("rld") + "o" + "w" + " " + "o" + "l" + "l" + "e" + "h" =
reverse("ld") + "r" + "o" + "w" + " " + "o" + "l" + "l" + "e" + "h" =
reverse("d") + "l" + "r" + "o" + "w" + " " + "o" + "l" + "l" + "e" + "h" =
reverse("") + "d" + "l" + "r" + "o" + "w" + " " + "o" + "l" + "l" + "e" + "h" =
```

Here we meet the base case, recursion stops and empty string is returned. Now all of the open stack frames collapse, starting with the deepest frame returning its value to its caller -

```js
"" + "d" + "l" + "r" + "o" + "w" + " " + "o" + "l" + "l" + "e" + "h" =
"d" + "l" + "r" + "o" + "w" + " " + "o" + "l" + "l" + "e" + "h" =
"dl" + "r" + "o" + "w" + " " + "o" + "l" + "l" + "e" + "h" =
"dlr" + "o" + "w" + " " + "o" + "l" + "l" + "e" + "h" =
"dlro" + "w" + " " + "o" + "l" + "l" + "e" + "h" =
"dlrow" + " " + "o" + "l" + "l" + "e" + "h" =
"dlrow " + "o" + "l" + "l" + "e" + "h" =
"dlrow o" + "l" + "l" + "e" + "h" =
"dlrow ol" + "l" + "e" + "h" =
"dlrow oll" + "e" + "h" =
"dlrow olle" + "h" =
```

And finally we can close the outermost call to `reverse` and return the result -

```
"dlrow olleh"
```

In this program, the **stack** is used to sequence operations and combine resulting values in the intended order. If the input `word` was significantly large, you would run into a **stack overflow** because too many frames would be opened and you essentially break the JavaScript runtime limit for such computations. Memory or **heap** is only used for all of the intermediate string allocations.

---

The ever-growing stack in the program above demonstrates a **recursive process**. This is characteristic of any recursive program that doesn't use a **tail call**. A tail call is simply the *last* call in your function, returned directly to its caller -

```js
function reverse(word) {
  function loop(r, w) {
    if (w == "") return r
    return loop(w[0] + r, w.substr(1)) // <- loop is the last called
  }
  return loop("", word)
}

console.log(reverse("hello world"))
```

This demonstrates a **linear iterative process**, so called because the process created by the recursive function stays flat and straight like a line -

```js
reverse("hello world") =
loop("", "hello world") =
loop("h", "ello world") =
loop("eh", "llo world") =
loop("leh", "lo world") =
loop("lleh", "o world") =
loop("olleh", " world") =
loop(" olleh", "world") =
loop("w olleh", "orld") =
loop("ow olleh", "rld") =
loop("row olleh", "ld") =
loop("lrow olleh", "d") =
loop("dlrow olleh", "") =
"dlrow olleh"
```

Some languages have **tail call optimization** which means the recursive function like the one above would be safe from the stack overflow problem. The compiler or runtime effectively converts the recursive call into a loop -

```js
function reverse(word) {
  function loop(r, w) {
    while (true) {
      if (w == "") return r
      r = w[0] + r
      w = w.substr(1)
    }
  }
  return loop("", word)
}

console.log(reverse("hello world"))
```

Above only **2 frames** are used and memory allocations of **3 bindings**, `word`, `r` and `w`. Memory allocations to compute `+` and `w.substr(1)` are also made and are recaptured by the runtime's automatic garbage collector.

In **ECMAScript 6**, tail call elimination was [added to the specification](https://2ality.com/2015/06/tail-call-optimization.html) however it is unsupported in almost every popular runtime and that is unlikely to change. That doesn't mean however we are constrained to writing recursive programs using imperative style `while` loops. There are [various techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43596323/633183) to make recursive programs safe even in JavaScript, even in runtimes that do not support this optimization.

Consider this implementation of `reverse` using `loop` and `recur` -

```js
const reverse = word =>
  loop
    ( (r = "", w = word) =>
        w == ""
          ? r
          : recur(w[0] + r, w.substr(1))
    )
```

The **non-recursive** `loop` and `recur` functions are generic and allow us to use them to write most recursive programs that will **not** cause a stack overflow -

```js
const recur = (...values) =>
  ({ recur, values })
  
const loop = run =>
{ let r = run ()
  while (r && r.recur === recur)
    r = run (...r.values)
  return r
}
```

```js
console.log(reverse("hello world"))
```

This has a very similar performance profile to the `while` loop above. Only **2 stack frames** and **3 bindings** with an small overhead of some immediately garbage-collected values like `+`, `substr` and `recur` -

Expand the snippet below to verify the result in your own browser -

```js
const recur = (...values) =>
  ({ recur, values })
  
const loop = run =>
{ let r = run ()
  while (r && r.recur === recur)
    r = run (...r.values)
  return r
}

const reverse = word =>
  loop
    ( (r = "", w = word) =>
        w == ""
          ? r
          : recur(w[0] + r, w.substr(1))
    )
    
console.log(reverse("hello world"))
```

```js
"dlrow olleh"
```

In fact, any recursive program, **tail call or not**, can be made stack-safe using various techniques. If this sort of thing sounds interesting to you, see [this related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57739457/633183) for an in-depth exploration of the topic.

Comment: He ordered an entrée, and you delivered an entire meal!

Comment: computation for the people ^_^

Comment: amazing answer, thank u so much you are awesome and have a great day.