# Tail recursion elimination on conditional types doesn't work

Tags: typescript, types, functional-programming, continuation-passing, trampolines

In TS 4.5 tail call optimization [was added](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-5/#tailrec-conditional) for recursive generics. The following snippet computes Fibonacci numbers (in unary) up to F<sub>12</sub>, but for F<sub>13</sub> it fails with the usual "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite" exception. This implementation of the Fibonacci function was chosen because it uses two calls of itself in non-tail-call positions, and is important for demonstration purposes.

The only recursive function here is `Run`, the rest of functions (and `interface`-based function references) should not significantly modify current stack depth. Why TCO didn't work, and how to make it work again?

```js
type Done<A> = { type: 'done', value: A };
type More<F, X> = { type: 'more', value: X, fn: F };
type FlatMap1<X, F> = { type: 'flatMap', value: X, fn: F }

interface FlatMap2<G, F> { a: unknown; r: FlatMap<Call<G, this['a']>, F> }
type FlatMap<X, F> = X extends FlatMap1<infer X, infer G> ? FlatMap1<X, FlatMap2<G, F>> : FlatMap1<X, F>

type Run<T> =
    T extends Done<infer V> ? V :
    Run<
        T extends More<infer F, infer X> ? Call<F, X> :
        T extends FlatMap1<infer X, infer F> ?
            X extends Done<infer V> ? Call<F, V> :
            X extends More<infer G, infer V> ? FlatMap<Call<G, V>, F> :
            X extends FlatMap1<infer V, infer G> ? FlatMap<V, FlatMap2<G, F>> :
            never :
        never
    >

interface Fib2<X> { a: unknown; r: Done<Add<X, this['a']>> }
interface Fib1<N> { a: unknown; r: FlatMap<More<FibR, Sub<N, '11'>>, Fib2<this['a']>> }
interface FibR { a: unknown; r: Fib<this['a']> }
type Fib<N> =
    N extends ('' | '1') ? Done<N> :
    FlatMap<
        More<FibR, Sub<N, '1'>>,
        Fib1<N>
    >

type R1 = Run<Fib<'1111111111111'>>

// utils

interface Fn { a: unknown; r: unknown }
type Call<F, X> = F extends Fn ? (F & {a: X})['r'] : never;

type Add<A, B> = A extends string ? B extends string ? `${A}${B}` : never : never
type Sub<A, B> = B extends string ? A extends `${B}${infer D}` ? D : never : never
```

[Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9gOwgHgIID4oF4oG8qiQBcUA5ACaISkA0UAbgIYA2ArhCalAL4DcAUIWgBZOACcUAMToANTDnxCSpALbjqdJmw5QZdAGYISkngKFRJzRsGGMwARmR6L8vAXA7S%20qzbu0GLOwkzobGPPz8AJYIwBBi%20owAxtCW1rZgAEzIAOJ0kpj4jCSsCADWCHAA7gi8UGLGPunIAMIszDl0wAAWkQDOANqkjKQAuuh5mNyCHhaNdk4T2LpQEAAesQjkvbNpdo7R%20nG6dAdH2ZgA-Du%20DgvX6Vm5LpgNu7fO%20RHmAEolyAAq8n4UBBUH%20K3WEE223gSGQpzEUAAapdkVAiMDQb8EMhMaDQeC1hstlBRBJ4QhDojpFAEbpUa1mO0aXJ0Xj8WCIcTtqkbvtKUdnHT8lALuyOaCZFyoSTYSg6SjRVBGcy6IqMRKJVKiTLtmT5QLEU8FajeU0VR1keMXGzNRztZDofc9hSqciToaoOclWb5ki8nNMpb8i9xZqkPQjhrwxBI2J2egItFYvEkilIgAjLKswrFMoVaq1eqwKhocjkO7dPqDYZjSZRGJxBLJCyZxwAOQKUCKUBK5SqNTqrxuyH1yEkme%20dAAyqwM8h23RSPZ7KR0NaJ1nkFWBkNRuvwsmm2nWxnvm4e32C4Pi5vtz1d7X6%20Y753sOz29KnQAKUikKAAD5kKuACUSpyguob4r6YC4naY6blOUCzvOi7AWu4xhiCm4dom%20KJtMkBQN89hLNi46Zsgy4rjRtE0RhEQAPSMb2wCRMwvRJo2qYtpICAXnm-aFkOvb5gO4TmBaLKuCYOpOnxSrfiYABkeA9jI3AgYMYijOiUARnEAiEdAqDlmgdAAEKuFwckkr0wBiNEADmSoWV%20dkOc5SoAAYACS4Kg3D%20RZ3DeXpBmIiQEXGchc7mVAVlLG5tnbPZjkIC5Vw2Y6JJ%20bgIX%20XSMCheB4WxlG%20nlWIQA)

#### What happens when TCO works?

Equivalent JavaScript (and intentionally ugly to prove it) code computes much bigger Fibonacci numbers (bigger than F<sub>35</sub>), barring conversion of tail recursion to explicit loop, and using binary numbers instead of unary. The only limit here is size of the heap, because the whole computation was trampolined (read [here](https://blog.higher-order.com/assets/trampolines.pdf) about this exact approach, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57733363/how-to-adapt-trampolines-to-continuation-passing-style/57743504#57743504) is more reader-friendly explanation of the concept).

```js
const done = a => ({type: 'done', value: a});
const more = (f, x) => ({type: 'more', value: x, fn: f});
const flatMap1 = (x, f) => ({type: 'flatMap', value: x, fn: f});

const flatMap2 = (g, f) => y => flatMap(g(y), f);
const flatMap = (x, f) => x.type === 'flatMap' ? flatMap1(x.value, flatMap2(x.fn, f)) : flatMap1(x, f);;

const run = tt => {
    for (let t = tt;;) {
        if (t.type === 'done') { return t.value; } else
        t = (() => {
            if (t.type === 'more') { return t.fn(t.value); } else
            if (t.type === 'flatMap') { const x = t.value, f = t.fn;
                if (x.type === 'done') return f(x.value);
                else if (x.type === 'more') return flatMap(x.fn(x.value), f); 
                else if (x.type === 'flatMap') return flatMap(x.value, flatMap2(x.fn, f));
                else throw new Error();
            }
            else throw new Error();
        })();
    }
};

const fib2 = x => y => done(x + y)
const fib1 = n => x => flatMap(more(fib, n - 2), fib2(x));
const fib = n => n < 2
    ? done(n)
    : flatMap(
        more(fib, n - 1),
        fib1(n),
    );

console.log(run(fib(30)));
```

[Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJuApjAvDAhqgfDAFAbygE8AHRALhgHIExEqAaGAN3QBsBXCjAXwEoA3AChQkWAFsQAJ2RpcAMyYAPPtjyFS3KpJmMW7LpSVN5YSvP7DR0GPLbooAWXQkAjKjzHbqlDgLEySio7B2cSPVZObi9Tc0shEXAbEKcXACYPXABzEx8cIjUUsOzcIj5cqyTYIpdMmLyYJQA6ANkUNGD7VPCYAH5bLrDXXGbIrhNB9JGm01zVc0m3EYrhRLEYKQ4wDyhYXxh8IRhj22k8NkRYPZhdgQFVQ5OnmABLeTwoFs1UdupaegeG0uHCk20%20Y0QAhgPBgiDYEEQR2ex2uuFwDUeyOebw%20XzIPw6OgBByBUBBYJmYFw4IMiEE0Nh8MRWOx72peLaHRq4UB1lgSh2TQhJkFpmELJZOOmrQJfyQVFUMjJoNs0whgiREuecIRrzZzRl7UJ0mJSvJA1CLmmpjVtPK3ihmq1Jx1yClBu%20Ruo3IVpPN3NtUQmlpIaWtYDm4udT1dNwAFlIQAB3GB0FMAUSkiak6KjWp4TpZsagCeTqcQGaz0lzhZO-BrTwLPFWfNsLwARhk0AL9gV9v8RjAANQwMprZId9xobb7Hs4ANEhQdpjbAC0MDS9vkHbDKg1re37Y8M5w2wAPBunf0B2A%20E6FiHcLXjovDyuYOvXOVn2328NbwwToauOIAXE0bAgFkuCbFSh64AAzAADHwKFQgA9GhqYcOI7aIFIMDAOg2y4RgEAwO2LxZKRMDiIgOgFOwEFJhAQA)

Comment: (Secretly hoping jcalz has some tricks up his sleeve again.)

Comment:  on mobile now but I’ll look when I get a chance… of course this looks pretty complex so I don’t have much hope I’ll be able to do something better.

Comment: Can you explain why "This implementation of the Fibonacci function was chosen because it uses two calls of itself in non-tail-call positions, and is important for demonstration purposes"?  Maybe I'm just tired but why aren't you trying to get the best unary fib function as possible here? Are you trying to use tail-call optimization or not?  If I were trying to write fib I'd do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOP3pN); presumably you'd have done so too if your goal was to actually compute this.  So what is the goal?  Is there some more motivating example here?

Comment: @jcalz This fib is chosen because it's non-tail-recursive. Then it's converted to CPS form and executed with `Run` that allows it to regain stack-safety. Basically this was an attempt to allow arbitrary computations at compile-time with no "instantiation depth" in mind.

Comment: Recently I've checked whether generic compile-time parsers are possible (https://gist.github.com/polkovnikov-ph/499c5a381b486c62ff11a010fa77e165). Nether sequencing nor selection is tail-recursive, so I needed some PoC of compile-time trampolining.

Comment: Yeah, okay, I understand now.  I guess I wish your example had been something a little less easily written directly, so I didn't spend any time wondering why one would intentionally write a bad fib implementation and then try to CPS-ify it.  But I get the point of the exercise now, at least.

Comment: yikes, 20 lines of type code for a 3-line function. maybe try typescripting [Aadit M Shah's Trampoline Monad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58949915/633183)?

Comment: @Mulan If I get it right, Shah's implementation is still stack-unsafe when there is a certain chain of `bind`s. The implementation above is the way it's usually implemented in Scala. There is a reference to an article in the question (right next to the reference to your article actually :) describing the caveats.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph read closely, in the post Shah describes how the `Loop` monad can lead to stack overflows, but the `Trampoline` monad _is_ stack safe. Not sure which article you are referencing, maybe you can link it?

Comment: @Mulan The problem is that it can be *kinda stack safe* until you do some really nasty recursion. IIRC even in source of one of the major Scala libraries it was initially implemented incorrectly. Unfortunately I constrained myself on the time spent to achieve the goal, and didn't really delve any deeper. Article is [here](https://blog.higher-order.com/assets/trampolines.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it seems I should have been reading better, because [in PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/45711) Anders clearly states that it's still limited:

> the compiler now performs type resolution in a loop that consumes no extra call stack. We permit evaluation of such types to **loop 1000 times** before we consider the type non-terminating and issue an error.

This would mean we're out of fortune, and Turing-complete computations of arbitrary complexity are impossible, if I didn't learn a trick back in C++ days.

Let's state the problem: we're iterating a certain function numerous times until it "completes". Let's use some simpler function: the one that concatenates a 1 to a string.

```js
type Test0<X> = X extends string ? `${X}1` : never
```

We can iterate it twice in this way:

```js
type Test1<X> = Test0<Test0<X>>
// Test1<''> = '11'
```

Each next iteration like this will multiply number of iterations by two:

```js
type Test2<X> = Test1<Test1<X>>
// Test2<''> = '1111'
```

We abstract over the number of iterations of doubling by adding an extra argument: (unary) number of doublings.

```js
type TestN<X, L extends string> = L extends `1${infer L}` ? TestN<TestN<X, L>, L> : Test0<X>
// TestN<'', '1111111111111111'> = '<one 65536 times>'
```

This allows us 2<sup>999</sup> iterations of `Test0` with `TestN<'', 'one 999 times'>`. After that we'll hit instantiation limit. Of course, we don't usually use all the 2<sup>N</sup> iterations for every function, so in order to exit early we return some "done" value.

```js
type Ten = '111111111'
type Test0<X> =
    // exit condition
    X extends Ten ? {done: X} :
    // body
    X extends string ? `${X}1` : never

type TestN<X, L extends string> =
    L extends `1${infer L}`
        // const m = testN(x, l);
        ? TestN<X, L> extends infer M
            // if done, exit early, otherwise continue
            ? M extends {done: any} ? M : TestN<M, L>
            : never
        : Test0<X>
// this is very fast compared to possible 2^32 iterations
TestN<'', '11111111111111111111111111111111'>["done"] = Ten
```

Let's talk about performance. If we called `TestN` from `TestN` K times instead of 2, we'd get at most K<sup>999</sup> iterations of `Test0`, but even for `K = 2` it will be able to iterate until the heat death of the universe.

When the function will be exiting, it will go through "passthrough" route at most once per level (`O(K)`), multiplied by at most the iteration depth `O(L)`. In order to reduce extraneous computations, branching level should be the smallest (choice of 2 was good), as well as depth aka doubling count.

With this approach I was immediately [able to compute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.0-beta#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLAEYCYA8ANAPmQG9k4AuZAVxAGsQB7AdxAG5kpKARBkCHAMJwANggB0AZSoBbfABpkYABbAAzgG0A5HE0BdAkQC%20AKFCRYiFOgwBGHADkipCtTqMW7TmmFwwAWTgABxw-Bih%20awAlBSFRMS5gGBgHBU0sTQMFa1xlNS0dfSNTcGh4JDRMSJIyShp6ZjYOSmscXI1tPSKwAE9Aq0wHIgBeY2Qx5HtkCAAPSBAAE1VkAApNAAZNZAAfZE0bTQBKZAB%20ZB4%20QeRyUfHUH38gnBvx8dDwnCiYkXEEpJTd-aZZ4vCq2QbAgjGYw9PrISI2ZBDOE0D4DPYATgykOMAHocdQwMBhKooTCUABBYTCc78cnDapkyjaKk0zQKABuIioEEo5OQJjJZ14tPppEZu3mwrZyE5wm5vP5rGhvRQbwiCkIiIZKqZ0jCEGlsvlyDwChgIGaiuVsLuvgCgTsprQosUOt2MHu9sNXJ5JrNFrQ-KhZlKlm8dqCuAA4lknDVXPUPE1ww9grFhDgY4oVO0CgRY0HBbbU-JnVq8FNZhAFkti-a7KAYNA-chG82o0RTnWgo6sp7I5nY0Rmv2HaXUNjBRJIMEACrDYGzytzRZCi5tqDIABqne3V0Xy%20rq7VOA3aAUZ81p3THw1w4PMxXtdHDZATc3TrPE5OwJeFcfR5LDSp5vs2O4nMgN6oAo4HXCC4z-lWNbICeZ5Zme4FdqOggiBmWY7gWcHwSah7Id2Y4YReoGbh2EHkTgW59hGgTRkO%207EcgfDss2RFjLO1ooAAMhA3EZk6gmkauqhgFAoAAOYLi8EkAchAAGNgACTEGegmGKpv7jKcwmiaWglECpq5nn4BnwacfiSUBwoge%20KG7vZlDGRAGZ%20AoZk2SClBcdA-mUNOEDBIQAnIiAODzlqnkZrOqQ2ClqVpelGWAsGJQWOUqAgNULh1O4jReMVDSFiqkG4beJr0qgDloAVpzLA1ABkJAuHghgHFoUB6FcnEidASrGCAcDSBAqiBGGsQICQwKCpEw1QKotKNdJskgApWp8hZSyqVpZ4ABKGEd1HILOekQYdxDLdxq38POZ3EKdqmDeSi1VcdEBwPMsX0ku%203ILdJ0vXAIDdNdpzHYN6yaF9sKznARIA1qQNIaut2bfJL1nld72nEuTIIy8goCLwCC%20Dg5IKAAQvSe2Y0sOPbRBdMbTJ8k3Vp5IvXT12BStg1BVAiMoPYMhLEiWgbMl0ppArADMCsACwKwArArABsCsAOwKwAHArmK6OLyASEoVBJMIT2NRD3TqPo6ONeoJ0KGInv47oEHqJ7YhJcgx0%200LD3mwEtAQMjGC27F9uQ07CgSPHjvO0iGNPsg6gOx7XsXbOPunOoEi52IEdR3AMdPUnVs2-wEgGCHWdm2TVVSNI0e21q5ed-wkvSKoCj96okKt7C7dcFqxBrKFMi9woNihbXHr13Ple2wQJhjygACSCwzDgdMKHSu2NZH3QMDAyAc6cdPqOSTei%20bQhQLJU1auoawKF-yA-3-38AN-oAn%20NgF5gOQKAiB4DIEwIXroJU29qqv26L3bucBI69xwJ-Uuw9dBfFfsAKao9xhThkAIKeM8kFQBQevCAC8l7WxXjhZBvdN7m0EgwBgtAqBzhiMfem9I97zAPkIkR%209pixRiPmIOv1-p0mkT9P6h8DDm3bhIGmnMtpyXppo%20SMQtRrHpBTEAVMwA0wEY1TQpNiLXkagiU4exNgkxCpBSm1M1GxRRhmOkChkaowZr5Th3DgjtwEHw5AtNr6ZGQBwrhPCcAT3CZEhmxCxgzECGEMArpx4yHMVE0%20wNWZyXZrotmpwPH3WgGtGm0jKmPWUcOIaD0RYrXNgAVRAKoZescM6ATIAnNOl1Xb%203dq2fOhcs6B39sHFpYdEE91oXYXpyEHaJwtinJ2gNXY52QCM8ZvsS67M9gsquSyFAdK6Yw2ODcCBNyds-aQgRUFIhObbOw2CjliFwfgt%20I8HksTyQzLUoiJEgsEI8%20eMilHyIUIo-6KT-lK0BUYx5uBknmWZr-CCAhUWH2PhizOawIKaCGE43YOAyUZGsWMcmjzVaAqkVqYxpjkWWM2LYygOLAga08ajHxl0vHKJiI8pF6KpH-J5ckpOjKkRcvpVK9ZwMSXssgoNBuwJ0mZOySgLlGjClc22jo-VWiUWBHpXU6p-KLX8ACbsUlqTtUTAgHJaWWdNCYlSMbVIBtUi61SFrVI6tUgq1SOkeWqQNgtxIVVX4MBnkoXQRXU5WCf7%202%20U6l1DrBSxsnkiae3BEhxtofQi23T%20CxtYVvaNsJY3kLzZQrlkLF6lqufwRttC2GINjeopmmcilGsxf21VSIbBGLcWY9FbL-K2OBvY3YlLqUBVcSY6m3beXeOkX4jMtrYnBJwLWpJAjpG7viTmw9USs1VXsAwYSSiG5amTkqjYEFk6hUaqpNY50XISGhhMG9siEmNIkBq6YGSoBZOzYW1lSJe19KKSU413NTjXtvf9Nd1qakKAwykxpotZnBUMEAA) F<sub>20</sub>, and it's not even remotely optimized. There is another undocumented limit though ([TS code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/TypeScript/main/src/compiler/checker.ts), `instantiateTypeWithAlias`) that enforces obfuscated code practices.

```js
instantiationCount >= 5000000
```